# Can I Use Visual Source Safe with Visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-sourcesafe

Can i use visual source safe with visual studio 2013 ?

I can only see GIT and Team Foundation ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution :

Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug-in Selection and change the plug in to the Visual SourceSafe.

Adding a solution to source control will launch the old VSS.

I haven't seen an answer for this question so i'd leave the question for others who stumble upon it.

Comment: I have used "plug-in selection" option hundreds of times to switch between TFS and Mercurial but it didn't strike me that VSS would also be there.

Comment: Do you know if this is available for VS Web Express 2013? I don't see VSS listed in the Plugin-Selection dropdown?

Comment: I have the VS 2013 premium edition. It is possible that some features won't be available in the express edition and source control could be among them. Is the VSS client already installed on your computer ? i think it is a must before you could choose it from the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, VSS is installed. I think it's that Express restriction since I can see my VSS listed in Plugins list in the VS2010 Pro edition. Thanks.

Comment: You may have to restart VS if it was open and you just installed VSS, as there will be Visual SourceSafe option in the list

Answer (score 1):

You should note that SourceSafe has a [long list of problems](http://www.abstrakti.com/SourceSafe) and annoyances.
Why don't you migrate to something more stable like TFS, Subversion, or Git?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it in visual studio 2013. [image]