# Visual Sourcesafe in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-sourcesafe

I have Visual Studio 2013 and I have a number of projects in Visual Studio Online, but I still have some old projects that are in Visual Source Safe.  It works fine on two pcs but we have a third that when you try to set you source control Visual Source Safe does not show up.

Doe anyone have any ideas on how to add Visual Source Safe to VS 2013 so it will show as a choice in the dropdown.

Comment: This might be a duplicate question and possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970797/can-i-use-visual-source-safe-with-visual-studio-2013?rq=1

Comment: Yes I saw that question but for some reason Visual Source safe never shows in the drop down on the one pc.  It works perfectly on two other machines but for reason just not this one.

Comment: It might be that you need to have VSS installed before you install VS. I'm not sure though; I noticed that I don't have VSS as an option in my VS13 Ultimate either. I guess moving to TFS or Git would be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft support:

> Visual Source Safe is no more is an active product and its no surprise
>   if the plugin is not available in Visual Studio 2013 as Microsoft
>   stopped supporting it long ago and its replaced by Team Foundation
>   Server. If you are still using Visual Source Safe, its recommended to
>   upgrade to Team Foundation Server.
>
> You can use Team Foundation Server Express (up to 5 users) for free
>   and use the [Visual SourceSafe Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/new-visual-source-safe-upgrade-tool-is-available.aspx) to import your project
>   directly into TFS. Or buy a full server from $400 and up.
>
> Alternatively, you can open a Visual Studio Online account (free for 5
>   users) and migrate your sources to the cloud. You can add additional
>   users for a monthly license fee.
>
> If you are an MSDN subscriber or Microsoft Partner, your subscription
>   might actually include a full TFS license.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40136b63-96ab-4807-9599-ca80c3a7bb7a/how-to-open-visual-source-safe-in-visual-studio-2013-express?forum=tfsversioncontrol

**Update** : I've found that you have to install the VSS after VS2013 on your system. please reinstall it.

Comment: Yes I know this, but it still does not explain why it works fine on two pcs but bit the third.  I did move it to Visual Studio Online, but personally I prefer having the code based saved locally and VSS has worked perfectly in VS2013 for the past 2 years.

Comment: I've found that you have to install the VSS after VS2013 on your system. please reinstall it

Comment: Yep I guess it does not like getting installed out of order